# Why use "on day" in Apple 3.1 Swift Tour "functions"-sample?

Tags: swift, function

I'm referring to an example in the Apple 3.1 Swift Tour:

```
func greet(_ person: String, on day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person), today is \(day)."
}
greet("John", on: "Wednesday")
```

In the function head it states "`on day`" whereas in the `return` statement, the code only refers to "`day`" and finally, when calling the function, it only assigns a value to "`on`". Why "`on day`" in the first place? Why not just "`day`"?

Comment: See also the section [Functions - Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) in the Swift Language Guide.

Comment: `day` is the name of the 2nd parameter in the `greet` function. `on` is the name of the 2nd parameter when you call the function `greet`. They are the same variables, just different names according to the scope.